# Result of a column based on the max date of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am in the process of cleaning up some data. In the Employee table there are ID's who have a status of 'active' which needs to be changed based on another table's status (text_1). This is

```
SELECT e.BW_ID, max(oe.TEXT_1) as 'Employee Status', max(oe.text_1_eff_date) 'Effective Date'
FROM    EMPLOYEE e
INNER JOIN ORG_EMPLOYMENT oe on e.BW_ID = oe.BW_ID
WHERE e.CONTROLLED_GROUP_STATUS = 'active'
GROUP BY e.BW_ID
```

Which looks like this(sample data):

[image]

But the problem is that some of these employees have multiple status' on the OE table, so the `max(oe.text_1)` ends up just returning the greatest value (R>T) when it should be T because it has the `max(text_1_eff_date)`

How should I write my query to return the latest `oe.text_1` status for each employee? I'm using SQL Server 2012

Comment: I am just baffled.  You mention two tables in the question and query.  Then you show *one* table.  I don't know which that refers to.  You have an "active" status referenced in the query, but "T" in the data.  And the column names don't correspond at all.

Comment: You can use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY oe.BW_ID ORDER BY oe.text_1_eff_date DESC) AS seq` to get the *latest-per-group* row. In an outer query filter using `seq=1`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes, I know it's confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT e.BW_ID, oe.TEXT_1 AS Employee_Status, oe.text_1_eff_date AS Effective_Date,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.BW_ID ORDER BY oe.text_1_eff_date) AS SEQ
      FROM EMPLOYEE e INNER JOIN 
           ORG_EMPLOYMENT oe 
           ON e.BW_ID = oe.BW_ID
      WHERE e.CONTROLLED_GROUP_STATUS = 'active'
     ) t
WHERE SEQ = 1;
```